# As boolean on dynamic field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

I have a serialized field that I am using to store some dynamic values for an object.  I am accessing the values using method_missing as they can be different for every object.  Everything is working except for a boolean value.  When I do:

```
f.input :hb_failed, as: :boolean, label: false
```

It doesn't render the checkbox only the hidden field.  However if I do:

```
f.input :hb_failed, as: :boolean, label: ""
```

I get the desired result which is a checkbox with no label.  Is this intended behavior or a bug?